# UITableView crash on updates after text edit

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uitextfield

So I'm totally stumped by this one and tempted to call "OS bug".

I have a TableView controller with a single section, and in the header for that section there is an UITextField. Several operations result in rows being added/removed without a problem. However, as soon as text is edited in the header, and the keyboard dismissed, any insertion/removal of rows results in an immediate crash.

And it can actually be simplified further - simply calling beginUpdates/endUpdates on the table once the keyboard is dismissed is enough to cause a crash. The end of the callstack is:

```
_CFTypeCollectionRetain
_CFBasicHashAddValue
CFDictionarySetValue
-[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _updateWithItems:withOldRowData:oldRowRange:newRowRange:context:]
-[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _endCellAnimationsWithContext:]
-[UITableView endUpdates]
```

I've put together a minimal example that demonstrates the problem.

Complete Controller source: http://www.andrewgrant.org/public/TableViewFail.txt

Example Project: http://www.andrewgrant.org/public/TableViewCrash.zip

Most relevant code:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // create header view
    UIView* header = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, 320.f, 50.f)] autorelease];

    // text field
    UITextField* textField = [[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.f, 12.f, 300.f, 28.f)] autorelease];
    textField.text = @"Edit, then 'Save' will crash";
    textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
    textField.delegate = self;

    [header addSubview:textField];

    return header;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    // no purpose, but demonstrates updates work at this point
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];

    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    // immediate crash
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Worth noting - the crash occurs regardless of whether the textField delegate is the controller, or a totally unrelated object instance.

Comment: I looked at your project. It works fine in 3.x, but as you said, it crashes on 4.0 when you hit save. +1 for tricky bug :)

Comment: One thing that comes to mind is that your XIB file has a table view which points to RootViewController as its data source and delegate, while the root view controller in turn instantiates a TableViewFail instance and puts it "on top". Shouldn't be a problem, but you do have 2 tables stacked on top of each other there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an update - I submitted a bug report and repro case to Apple and they confirmed it's a bug in iOS 4.0. As of iOS 4.1 beta 2 it had not been fixed.

My work around was to turn the first row of my table into a pseudo header that occupies the entire content view and has a custom height. It's not quite as good (things cant reach to the edge of the screen for example) but it's close and doesn't crash.

Comment: crap.  I just got burned by this too.

Answer (score 1):

I hit this bug last night and spent a few hours this morning trying to figure it out.  The other answers in this thread didn't work for me, but did help me come up with a workaround that I think is best.

Cameron suggested making an offscreen UITextField the firstResponder, then resigning it before calling endUpdates on the tableview.  This didn't work for me, but it gave me an idea.

In the context of my custom header view, I re-parent the text field (in my case, a UISearchBar, actually) before calling resignFirstResponder.  Then I put it back:

```
[self.window addSubview: sb];
[sb resignFirstResponder];
[self addSubview: sb];
```

a few lines later, when I call [tableView endUpdates], it no longer crashes.

Edit:  It just got a bit more complicated.  The problem is that if first-responder status is otherwise revoked (for example, the user dismisses the keyboard), this parent-swapping code isn't executed, and we'll eventually get the crash.  My current fix is to place a category-override on UITextField resignFirstResponder -- seems to work but not sure yet if there are any adverse side effects.

```
@implementation UITextField (private)

- (BOOL) resignFirstResponder
{
    UIView* superviewSave = self.superview;
    [self.window addSubview: self];
    BOOL success = [super resignFirstResponder];
    [superviewSave addSubview: self];
    return success;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this bug myself and am so glad I found your post because I was banging my head on my desk trying to figure out where I screwed up.

For my workaround, I created an offscreen `UITextField` and called `becomeFirstResponder` and then `resignFirstResponder` on that text field before doing the updates.  This avoided the crash and didn't require any redesign of the headers or cells.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work for me.  I think I did what you described - create a UITextField, which I attached to the app's window, but alpha'd to be hidden.  Called [tf becomeFirstResponder] followed by [tf resignFirstResponder] - both succeed (and the keyboard slides away).  But I still get the crash when calling [tableView endUpdates] a few lines later.  Do you have any further hints?

Comment: This is what I ended up doing: `[hiddenField becomeFirstResponder];
  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0 target:self selector:@selector(dismissKeyboard:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];` and simply called resignFirstResponder in dismissKeyboard

Answer (score 0):

Taking Tom's solution one step further, I noticed this solution only works on iOS 4.X, which is ok because this problem only exists in iOS 4.X. Therefore I changed his method to:

```
@implementation customUITextField

- (BOOL)resignFirstResponder {

if ( [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion characterAtIndex:0] == '4' ) {

    UIView* superviewSave = self.superview;
    [self.window addSubview:self];
    BOOL success = [super resignFirstResponder];
    [superviewSave addSubview:self];
    return success;

}

return [super resignFirstResponder];

}

@end
```